# Swift 3 Parse query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, swift3

I have errors after i updated swift 2 to swift 3

```
var nicknames = [String]()
var messages = NSArray()
var selectedmsg:PFObject!

query.findObjectsInBackground{
(objects, error) -> Void in

if error == nil
{
 messages = objects!   ***Cannot assign value of type '[PFObject]?' to type 'NSArray'***

for object in objects! {

  self.nicknames.append(object.object(forKey: "userpointer")!.object(forKey: "nickname") as! String)  ***Value of type 'Any' has no member 'object'***
}


self.selectedmsg = messages.object(at: (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row) as! PFObject

self.selectedmsg["file"]!.getDataInBackground{ ***Value of type 'Any' has no member 'getDataInBackground'***
```

There is three errors in the code between ***

the code was working good in swift 2, Can someone please help me to fix same code in swift 3
Please any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why this website have no answers anymore?

Comment: how did you solved it I have the same problem, which is your second error?

Comment: @saner Show me your code with errors in pastebin.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, **do not use `NSArray` in Swift unless you have no choice**.

`NSArray` doesn't provide any type information so the compiler does not know that it actually  contains `PFObject` objects.

In this case you have a choice! Enlighten the compiler by declaring `messages` as

```
var messages = [PFObject]()
```

This slightly change will solve all three errors.

Comment: Thank you, it only fixed first error. But i still have errors because var messages has been changed to pfobject. see this: https://i.gyazo.com/bb014d1d308b57c67b8bf05714f54492.png

Comment: You have to cast the `Any` values to the proper type. And if key subscription does not work try `objectForKey`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and show me example with codes and how to take each row as i did with NSArray? it will be helpful.

Comment: This depends on the type of the value in the dictionary. For example the value for key `file` is most likely `PFObject`, so you have write `(self.selectedmsg["file"] as! PFObject).getDataInBackground...`, and instead of `objectAtIndex` try index subscripting `objects[indexPath.row]`. Unfortunately I don't use Parse at all. you could also try to retype methods to get the exact Swift 3 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to change to fix my app from working in Swift 3

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

and all prepare segues:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed to that func application, but still same errors. I dont know about prepare segues because appdelegate default i didn't added funcs there